# MaximalBy[#, "votes"] & not equal to MaximalBy["votes"]?

Tags: dataset, filtering, maximum

I'm looking at the results of the 2015 UK general election

```
ukp2015raw = Import["http://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/CBP-7186/hocl-ge2015-results-full.csv", "CSV"];
```

Which I choose to store as a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)

```
ukp2015 = Dataset@Map[AssociationThread[ukp2015raw[[1]] -> #] &, ukp2015raw[[2 ;;]]];
```

To get the most voted candidate for of each constituency I use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html)

```
ukp2015[GroupBy["constituency_name"], MaximalBy["votes"]]
```

Which gives the correct answer. But, I would have expected the same output from

```
ukp2015[GroupBy["constituency_name"], MaximalBy[#, "votes"] &]
```

**Why do I get a different answer from the later?**

(Using Mathematica 11.1.0.0 on Windows 7 Pro SP1  64 bits)

Ultimately I would want to select all constituencies where party X won, but party Y or Z would have won if Y and Z selectively dropped candidates and a given percentage of votes are inherited. The thing is that the [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) statements get complicated by the fact that `MaximalBy[#, "votes"] &` doesn't give me the expected output.

Comment: I get the same answer. What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: You're right, the answer is not the same.  I am not really a great fan of these generalizations of `Dataset`.  `MaximalBy` should have a function as the second argument and `"votes"` is of course not a function.  Normally `MaximalBy["votes"]` doesn't work, but Dataset/Query treat it specially and make it work.  Then I have to remember which exact functions are treated specially ... What makes it even more confusing is that using `"votes"` where a function is expected does not cause an error because Mathematica can't really tell what is a "function". Any expression can be used with arguments.

Comment: I think the clearest thing to do is to use a proper function: use `#votes&` instead of `"votes"`.

Comment: I think this is the relevant line in the Query documentation (under Details): *The syntax `GroupBy["string"]` can be used as a synonym for `GroupBy[Key["string"]]`. The same syntax is also available for `SortBy`, `CountsBy`, `MaximalBy`, `MinimalBy`, and `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.*  Implicitly, then `GroupBy[..., "string"]` cannot be used as such a synonym.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs!  Indeed, `ukp2015[GroupBy["constituency_name"], MaximalBy[#, Key["votes"]] &]`. I agree that many features of `Dataset` create inconsistencies and confusion. In any case `Key` does not return a function, does it?

Comment: In conclusion, my question comes from not understanding well the documentation (ignoring this was just a shortcut that works only for a particular form).Is then my question off-topic? I'm willing to close it, if necessary. But the explanation was buried in the Query documentation, it was not obvious to me.

Comment: `Key["thing"]` is a function that can be applied to an association: `Key["a"][<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]`. It is equivalent to `#thing&`.

Comment: I do not think that this should be closed. I was confused too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, `fun` in

```
MaximalBy[fun]
```

or

```
MaximalBy[list, fun]
```

must be a function. But [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) and `Dataset` are special, and they accept a column name (or generally: association key) in `MaximalBy` as well as some other functions when using them in their operator form.  From the `Query` documentation:

> The syntax `GroupBy["string"]` can be used as a synonym for `GroupBy[Key["string"]]`. The same syntax is also available for `SortBy`, `CountsBy`, `MaximalBy`, `MinimalBy`, and `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.

Note that here `Key["string"]` is an operator:

```
Key["b"][<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]
(* 2 *)
```

This shorthand notation can only be used with operator forms such as `MaximalBy["string"]`, but not general forms like `MaximalBy[..., "string"]`.  The latter will try to apply `"string"` as a function.  This is why these two forms did not give you the same result.

#### Solution

Instead of using this shorthand, specify an explicit function in `MaximalBy`.  Either `Key["votes"]` or `#votes &` will work:

```
MaximalBy[#votes &]

MaximalBy[#, Key["votes"]]&

MaximalBy[#, #votes &] &
```